# Get first data-date value from given html

Tags: html, jquery

I want to find first date. The date saved in td attribute **data-date**. Here is my html.

```
<div class="fc-bg bsit_hours_background">
   <div class="fc-slats">
      <table>
         <colgroup>
            
         </colgroup>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td class="fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-today fc-state-highlight fc-day" data-date="2021-08-09">
                  <div></div>
               </td>
               <td class="fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-future fc-day" data-date="2021-08-10">
                  <div></div>
               </td>
               <td class="fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-future fc-day" data-date="2021-08-11">
                  <div></div>
               </td>
               <td class="fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-future fc-day" data-date="2021-08-12">
                  <div></div>
               </td>
               <td class="fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-future fc-day" data-date="2021-08-13">
                  <div></div>
               </td>
                ...........               
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
```

I have to use jQuery and find its date "2021-08-09". Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/chirag_parmar/k34b9w0o/13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access like this:

```
var dateForRestHours=jQuery('[data-date]');
console.log($(dateForRestHours[0]).attr("data-date"));
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c6hkmu9r/

Comment: Yes its working. Thanks. I found one more method.

Answer (score 1):

This returns the first `td`'s data attribute. In this example I echo the result to the console. That seems to be what you're looking for based on the question.

```js
let x = $("td").first().data("date");
console.log(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fc-bg bsit_hours_background">
  <div class="fc-slats">
    <table>
      <colgroup>

      </colgroup>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-today fc-state-highlight fc-day" data-date="2021-08-09">
            <div></div>
          </td>
          <td class="fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-future fc-day" data-date="2021-08-10">
            <div></div>
          </td>
          <td class="fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-future fc-day" data-date="2021-08-11">
            <div></div>
          </td>
          <td class="fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-future fc-day" data-date="2021-08-12">
            <div></div>
          </td>
          <td class="fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-future fc-day" data-date="2021-08-13">
            <div></div>
          </td>
          ...........
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){      
        var dateForRestHours= $('.fc-bg.bsit_hours_background .fc-slats table tr td').first().data("date");
alert(dateForRestHours);
});
```

I found this solution. Above [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68757829/get-first-data-date-value-from-given-html/68758015#68758015) of Suresh Kamrushi is also working.